# Find closest timestamp in dataframe to other timestamp for every row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Each row in the below dataframe is either a `trade` or a `quote` (as flagged on the `type` column).

For each `trade`, I've added columns on each row which is calculated with `timestamp (of a trade row) - a given time delta` (-2ms, -1ms, 1ms, 2ms).

I need to create a new column, for each of the `trade` rows, that has the `vol_imb` of a `quote` where the `timestamp` of that `quote` is the latest before each of the `-2ms, -1ms, 1ms, 2ms` timestamps of that row.

I solved it through iterrows, but it takes way to long to be scalable. Any ideas?

```
data = {
    'timestamp': [
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.500402164',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501007685',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501046799',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501047392',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501072886',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501085094',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501113901',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501138119',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.501160546',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.504998811',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.506396344',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.506418594',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.506427564',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.506477806',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.514936026',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.516790699',
        '2023-09-08 07:00:01.516817055'
    ],
    'vol_imb': [
        0.80, 0.95, 0.81, 0.76, -0.00, 0.74, 0.61, -0.35, 0.03, 0.13, -0.32, 0.13, -0.18, -0.00, 0.21, -0.09, 0.09
    ],
    'execution_size': [
        None, 38.0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 14.0, None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    'price': [
        None, 1365.0, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 1365.2, None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    'aggressor_side': [
        None, 'ASK', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'ASK', None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    'type': [
        'quote', 'trade', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'trade', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote', 'quote'
    ],
    '-1ms': [
        None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.500007685', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.505418594', None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    '-2ms': [
        None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.499007685', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.504418594', None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    '1ms': [
        None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.502007685', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.507418594', None, None, None, None, None
    ],
    '2ms': [
        None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.503007685', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '2023-09-08 07:00:01.508418594', None, None, None, None, None
    ]
}

# Convert the 'timestamp' column to datetime objects
data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data['timestamp'])

# Create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:
I would expect the trade to have 4 vol_imb cols, one at each time delta

```
First trade: -2ms=0.80 | -1ms=0.80 | 1ms = 0.03 | 2ms = 0.03
Second trade: -2ms=0.03 | -1ms=0.13 | 1ms = -0.00 | 2ms = -0.00
```

My iterrows approach:

```
time_buckets = ['1','2','3']

time_type = 'ms'

for i, row in trades.iterrows():
    trade_time = row['trade_timestamp']
    
    for time_bucket in time_buckets: 
        # time of trade - the time delta we want to look at 
        time_delta_before = trade_time - pd.Timedelta(time_bucket + time_type)
        # df of all imbalances before time delta
        imbal_before = bbo.loc[(bbo['event_timestamp'] <= time_delta_before) & (bbo['event_timestamp'] < trade_time)]
        # check that there is imbalance data
        if(len(imbal_before) > 0):
            # set imbalance of trade at time delta to latest element
            trades.loc[i,'-' + time_bucket] = imbal_before.iloc[-1].vol_imb 
        
        #time_delta_after = trade_time + pd.Timedelta(time_bucket + time_type)
        trades.loc[i,time_bucket] = bbo.loc[(bbo['event_timestamp'] >= time_delta_after) & (bbo['event_timestamp'] > trade_time) ].iloc[0].vol_imb
```

Comment: please provide the expected output and your `iterrows` approach

Comment: @mozway added the requested info

Comment: what are `'trade_timestamp'` and `'event_timestamp'` in your code? Make sure it runs fine with the provided dataset.

Comment: Ah yes, initially I had split the two into separate tables. ' trade_timestamp ' was the timestamp for trades table, ' event_timestamp ' was the timestamp for the quotes table. The solution you provided below works though. Tried for 2 days, you solved in 2 minutes... Many thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Out of curiosity, what are the timings with the loop approach and this one?

Comment: Bit difficult to compare because in the example you solved, I look only at the first 50 rows of a much larger dataframe which concatenates trades and quotes. In the iterrows way I solved it, the dataframes are separated and hence I can't take the same amount of data as I did in the first example. With that caveat: my solution: 0.547590970993042. your solution: 0.015987873077392578
And I expect my solution would blow up the more time deltas I add to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact logic and expected output are unclear, but this seems like a job for [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
def merge_last(s):
    return pd.merge_asof(
              pd.to_datetime(s.dropna()).reset_index(),
              df[['timestamp', 'vol_imb']],
              allow_exact_matches=False,
              left_on=s.name, right_on='timestamp'
            ).set_index('index')['vol_imb'].reindex(s.index)

cols = ['-1ms', '-2ms', '1ms', '2ms']

out = df[cols].apply(merge_last)
```

Output:

```
    -1ms  -2ms   1ms   2ms
0    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    NaN   NaN  0.03  0.03
2    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
6    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
7    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
8    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
9    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
10   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
11  0.13  0.03 -0.00 -0.00
12   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
14   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
15   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
16   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Note that this searches a match across **all** timestamps, if you want to do it per group that restart on each `trade` let me know, I'll update the answer with the `by` parameter. Also note that you need to ensure that the input DataFrame is sorted by `timestamp` for `merge_asof` to work correctly (which is the case here).